# I'm trying to use the p.adjust function and I get the error object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Tags: r

So I read in my text file first:

```
x <- read.csv('filename.txt')
```

Then I try and run the p adjustment:

```
p.adjust(x, method = "BH")
```

The problem is I get this error:

> Error in p.adjust(x, method = "BH") :
>     (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Can anyone please help in dealing with this? Not sure what it means or how to proceed.

Comment: The error is because x is a data.frame, whereas `p.adjust` expects a numeric vector. Try `str(x)` and from those results, pull the p-values from your tests for use in `p.adjust`. Something like `x$pvals`  where pvals is the name of the variable with p-values.

Comment: Can you please give me some more detail on how the code should look for that? I'm still very new to R. Thanks!

Comment: Paste the results of `str(x)` into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Little late to the party but this might help other people that get this problem.

The user Imo is correct that you're entering it in as a data frame instead of a numeric vector. Imo suggests converting it to a vector before processing.

You can do it a little easier (and without making a new data set) by using "as.matrix" in the same line. For your example:

```
p.adjust(as.matrix(x), method = "BH")
```